# What does "Network interrupted; server closed" mean?

Tags: wi-fi

My phone (a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini running Android 4.4.2) sometimes shows a message window with the text "Network interrupted; server closed". Does anybody know exactly what that means? I've tried googling it, but that doesn't get me anywhere.

The message is in English, even though I've set the phone to Dutch; other messages are in Dutch rather than English.

As far as I can see it happens when I get out of wifi range. I understand the "Network interrupted" part; seems normal if I go out of wifi range (though I'd rather expect something like "Connection lost"). What I don't understand is the "server closed" part. It seems to imply there is a server running on the phone -- does Android run some kind of server? Or is it possible that the message comes from some app that's running in the background rather than from Android itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the "File Expert with Clouds" application installed then it may be the culprit. I was having the same issue and suspected it may be that application because it seemed to start happening after I had started and then stopped the FTP server.
I removed the application and the messages stopped.
I then re-installed the application and everything was fine until I started and stopped the FTP server at which time the messages started to appear again.
I removed the application (permanently this time) and the messages have stopped again.
I didn't bother to check to see if I could connect to the FTP server when it was supposedly stopped but I may re-install the app one more time just to see if that's the case. I'll post the result here if I do get around to testing it... Paul

Comment: I have "File Expert" (with Clouds, I think) installed. I'll try uninstalling it (I don't use it all that often) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Since I removed "File Expert", I haven't seen the message anymore. Therefore I accepted your answer (even though there's a chance it's a coincidence). In addition I have the impression that my phone drains its battery much slower now (it's just an impression though, absolutely not scientifically measured).

Answer (score 1):

It is File Expert. I had it on 2 of my devices both showed the same toast notification "network interrupted;server closed" and stopped doing it after uninstalling.

Before ditching the app I tried getting into the devices through ftp (when shut down) but would not work so File Expert probably just constantly scans network activity and displays a toast when the network/wifi is down, keeping the device awake and draining battery. Some bad dev work there.

Try "Solid Explorer" instead, best file browser ever.